# Получить все значения словаря.

Tags: python, словари

Как можно получить все значения "number" из вот такого словаря в python.

```
d = {"content":[{"number":"100"},{"number":"200"},{"number":"300"}]}
```

Вот так я получаю лиш одно значение

```
print d["content"][0]["number"]
```

Думаю что нужно использовать цикл for

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for k in d.get('content'):
    print k.get('number')
```

Answer (score 8):

Можно for:

```
for item in d["content"]:
    print item["number"]
```

Можно получить список значений и работать уже с ним:

```
x = [item["number"] for item in d["content"]]
print x  # ['100', '200', '300']
```